# Codecademy Python “is_prime” exercise in “Practice Makes Perfect”-Is it really iterating?

Tags: python

This function is supposed to return True if a number is prime and False if it's not. The problem is that `is_prime(9)` returns `True`.

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x<2:
        return False
    elif x==2:
        return True
    elif x==3:
        return True
    else:
        for i in range(2,x):
            if x%i==0:
                return False
                break
            else:
                return True
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it return `True`?

Comment: @Amir Rouatbi Whenever a you return from a function, the function gets over and return to the point where it was called from.

Comment: Thanks! I unsderstood my mistake. Sorry if I bothered you. I'm still a beginner though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if you write

```
for i in range(2,x):
    if x%i==0:
        return False
        break
    else:
        return True
```

if `x` is `9` then `9%2 != 0`, so it takes `else` path and returns `True`

`odd_number % 2` is always `= 1`

You have to remove the last line and replace it with `return True` after the `for` has finished:

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x<2:
        return False
    elif x==2:
        return True
    elif x==3:       #<-- This one is useless, it will be already checked within the for
        return True
    else:
        for i in range(2,x):
            if x%i==0:
                return False
                break
        return True

print is_prime(9)
print is_prime(11)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is improperly indented. The `else:return True` line should be indented one level less, so that it runs after the for loop terminates. The current code returns `True` whenver **any** divisibilty test fails, not when **all of the** divisibility tests fail.

Comment: While technically, `else`s on `for` loops are a thing in Python, I doubt it was the OP's intention. It's kind of obscure. More likely, they meant to have the `else` inside the loop and just didn't realize that'd make it stop after the first check.

Comment: @user2357112 I disagree. Improper indentation in stack overflow code samples is a common thing.

Comment: Improper indentation is common, but it rarely takes this form. Usually, it's stuff like mixed tabs and spaces, or function bodies at 0 indentation level. The kind of erroneous code structure here is common even in languages like C and Java that don't have elses on for loops. Plus, the `break` after `return` indicates a lack of awareness that `return` already stops the function.

Answer (score 0):

Check indentation. The `if` and `else` in the `for` loop.
Understand the meaning of return, the function literally exits when you return.
Corrected code:

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x<2:
        return False
    elif x==2:
        return True
    elif x==3:
        return True
    else:
        for i in range(2,x):
            if x%i==0:
                print "Hello"
                return False
                break
        else:
            return True

print is_prime(9)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is buggy.  The `else:` inside the loop is returning `True` the first time it encounters a number that isn't a divisor.  That needs to be deleted, and the `return True` needs to be placed after the loop (outside of it).